# Who was Headmistress of Beacon versing in Episode 1: Ruby Red Rose?

Tags: rwby

In RWBY, Episode 1: Ruby Red Rose, we see Ruby chasing a criminal who stole dust. After she chased this criminal, he shot at her, thought he had gotten rid of her, but was saved by the headmistress of Beacon Academy.

Further on we see the headmistress fighting a highly skilled person on the helicopter. Who was this woman and will we learn more about her in season 2?

Comment: The contents of the second season are barely/not known at this point in time.

Comment: Also, the woman saving Ruby isn't the headmistress. Professor Ozpin is the headmaster, making Glynda, the woman, his secretary/assistant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is revealed that the woman was Cinder:

[image]

> Cinder Fall is a character in the world of RWBY. She appears to be affiliated with Roman Torchwick in some way, perhaps controlling, or at least coercing, Roman rather than cooperating with him

She is definitely a main character, she is also the antagonist and was the exact same woman that the headmistress was fighting against.